# Datatable Server Side Processing Sort Functionality works only once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have the following server side code which handles searching, sorting, and pagination. However, the sorting works only once per column. If I click on the sort again, it does not respond. Also, when I debugged the code, I saw that the sortBy and SortDir are correct. However, the result seems to be unaffected by these two variables.

Here's my code:

```
 public JsonResult CustomServerSideSearchAction(DataTableAjaxPostModel model)
 {
        // action inside a standard controller
        int filteredResultsCount;
        int totalResultsCount;
        var res = YourCustomSearchFunc(model, out filteredResultsCount, out totalResultsCount);

        var result = new List<Member>(res.Count);

        foreach (var s in res)
        {
            // simple remapping adding extra info to found dataset
            result.Add(new Member
            {
               Id = s.Id,
               CardNumber = s.CardNumber, 
               FullName   = s.FullName, 
               RegistrationDate = s.RegistrationDate,
               Address =    s.Address, 
               PhoneNumber = s.PhoneNumber, 
               Email = s.Email
            });
        };

        Debug.WriteLine(result); 

        return Json(new
        {
            // this is what datatables wants sending back
            draw = model.draw,
            recordsTotal = totalResultsCount,
            recordsFiltered = filteredResultsCount,
            data = result
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public IList<MemberDto> YourCustomSearchFunc(DataTableAjaxPostModel model, 
        out int filteredResultsCount, out int totalResultsCount)
    {
        var searchBy = (model.search != null) ? model.search.value : null;
        var take = model.length;
        var skip = model.start;

        string sortBy = "";
        bool sortDir = true;

        if (model.order != null)
        {
            // in this example we just default sort on the 1st column
            sortBy = model.columns[model.order[0].column].data;
            sortDir = model.order[0].dir.ToLower() == "asc";
        }

        // search the dbase taking into consideration table sorting and paging
        var result = GetMembers(searchBy, take, skip, sortBy, sortDir, out filteredResultsCount, out totalResultsCount);
        if (result == null)
        {
            // empty collection...
            return new List<MemberDto>();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public List<MemberDto> GetMembers(string searchBy, int take, int skip, string sortBy, 
        bool sortDir, out int filteredResultsCount, out int totalResultsCount)
    {
        var result = new List<MemberDto>(); 

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBy))
        {

            result = _context.Members                          
                       .Select(m => new MemberDto
                       {
                           Id = m.Id,
                           FullName = m.FullName,
                           RegistrationDate = m.RegistrationDate,
                           CardNumber = m.CardNumber,
                           Address = m.Address,
                           Email = m.Email,
                           PhoneNumber = m.PhoneNumber,

                       })
                       .OrderBy(sortBy, sortDir)
                        .Skip(skip)
                       .Take(take)     // have to give a default order when skipping .. so use the PK                           
                       .ToList();

            filteredResultsCount = _context.Members.Count();
        }

        else
        {                 
            result = _context.Members
                      .Where(p => p.FullName.Contains(searchBy))
                       .Select(m => new MemberDto
                       {
                           Id = m.Id,
                           FullName = m.FullName,
                           RegistrationDate = m.RegistrationDate,
                           CardNumber = m.CardNumber,
                           Address = m.Address,
                           Email = m.Email,
                           PhoneNumber = m.PhoneNumber,

                       })
                       .OrderBy(sortBy, sortDir) 
                       .Skip(skip)
                       .Take(take)
                       .ToList();
            filteredResultsCount = _context.Members.Where(p => p.FullName.Contains(searchBy)).Count();
        }

        totalResultsCount = _context.Members.Count();

        return result;
    }
```

Here's the view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#members').DataTable({

             "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: "@Url.Action("CustomServerSideSearchAction", "Member")",
                type: 'POST'

            },
            "language": {
                "search": "",
                "searchPlaceholder": "Search..."
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "CardNumber"
                },
                {
                    data: "RegistrationDate",

                },
                {
                    data: "FullName",

                },
                {
                    data: "Address"
                },
                {
                    data: "PhoneNumber"
                },
                {
                    data: "Email"
                },

            ],

        });
```

Can someone kindly tell me why the sorting works only once per column?

Comment: I think what you mean is when you click the column a 2nd time you don't get the column in reverse order.  Are you clicking the Fullname , then Address, and then Fullname again?

Comment: Nope, I am clicking fullname, it sorts in ascending. I click it again, it doesnt do anything. But your explanation is right.

Comment: See following line :  sortDir = model.order[0].dir.ToLower() == "asc";

Comment: What's wrong with that line? I checked it and if the sorting order is ascending, I get "true" and when is descending, then I get "false". SO it works fine.

Comment: and when you set a breakpoint in the controller, is `model.order[0].dir` being set appropriately on every request? and am I missing something here because I don't see an overload of `OrderBy` that has the signature `OrderBy(string s, bool b)`

Comment: Yes, it is being set appropriately every single time. 
And this is the orderBy definition: c IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering, params object[] values);

Answer (score -2):

solution : using Extension method

```
public static class GenericSorterExtension
{
    public static List<T> Sort<T>(this List<T> list, string sortBy_sortDirection)
    {
        string[] sortProperties = sortBy_sortDirection.Split(' ');
        
        //if(sortProperties.l > 2)
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

        var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>
            (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortProperties[0]), typeof(object)), param);

        switch (sortProperties[1].ToLower())
        {
            case "asc":
                list = list.AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy<T, object>(sortExpression).ToList();
                break;
            default:
                list = list.AsQueryable<T>().OrderByDescending<T, object>(sortExpression).ToList();
                break;
        }
        return list;
    }       
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).